# Command line tool for re-encoding MP3s?

Tags: mp3, encoding

I've got an [old and temperamental MP3 player](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16855199001) which doesn't deal well with MP3s that have fancy things like a variable bit rate.

Is there a command line tool for Mac or Linux that I could use to re-encode MP3s so they have a fixed bitrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Linux, consider FFmpeg -- ffmpeg.org/

For Windows, Linux or OSX, use lame -- http://lame.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

LAME is probably the best known name in the business, though it is a very advanced system and not for someone "new" to the command line.

Comment: Most of the GUIs use lame in the back-end, so you get my vote for mentioning it.

Comment: D'oh! I'd previously looked at lame, but for some reason I'd assumed that it only accepted WAV files. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out MP3Packer http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=32379 it can change files from vbr to cbr.